# Как Ajax`ом забрать JS c Web-морды IP камеры?

Tags: javascript, ajax

У нас в компании есть внутренний сайт,на котором есть доступ к IP камерам, суть такова - нажимаем на иконку камеры и выводится изображение, но есть одно НО : Поворотные камеры. 
Сейчас управление поворотными камерами сделано на JS под Django,но сделано кнопками,а это и не удобно и большая задержка отклика.

У камеры есть родная веб-морда,на которой находятся ползунки для управления (поворот,зум),они написаны на JS,так вот - как это выдернуть Ajax`ом на локальный сайт(на котором просматриваем камеры)

> [image: Управление камеры]

Ну и вот примерно вид самого JS скрипта

> [image: Буду признателен очень,если кто ещё поведает библиотеку данную]

**ПО ИТОГУ**: Нужно вытащить лишь УПРАВЛЕНИЕ поворотной камеры,а не видео поток и вставить в на другом сайте
Если нужна будет доп.информация,на всё отвечу,благодарю заранее)

Comment: Сделайте свои собственные ползунки без выдёргивания, не?

Comment: ajax-запросы можно просто посмотреть в мониторинге сети в инструментах разработчика любого браузера безо всякого выдёргивания

Comment: @andreymal Свои можно,через тот же Python onvif,но скорость отклика долгая,на поворотных камерах это порой неуместно (нужна максимально быстрая скорость работы). Ну вот и возникла идея с помощью Ajax выдернуть как нибудь html/js (форму управления со скриптом) напрямую на сайт,что бы по быстрее было. Ну а на счёт "просмотра запросов",это всё хорошо,но мне же их как-то надо использовать их,а следовательно надо запрос сделать,но вот как?

Comment: Как сделать ajax-запрос? Ответом на этот вопрос завален абсолютно весь интернет, неужели не нашли?

Comment: @andreymal Я искал,нашёл похожие запросы,но что бы одновременно дернуть HTML с JS внутри,не нашёл (может плохо искал,не отрицаю),вот и решил узнать у знающих людей,что бы объяснили - возможно ли это сделать без костылей и что релевантно ли это по скорости или может я просто ерундой откровенно занимаюсь и проще OnFiv

Comment: Что такое «дернуть HTML с JS» и зачем оно вам нужно? Посмотрели в мониторинге сети, каким запросом управляется камера → повторили в своём ajax-запросе → всё. А дальше к этому ajax-запросу прикручивайте какой угодно ползунок, какие угодно кнопки — выдёргивание ни к чему. При чём здесь вообще HTML?

Comment: Вот, к примеру, как это выглядит на одной из доступных мне камер Falcon Eye: https://i.imgur.com/wNm7edc.png — для поворота достаточно отправить запрос на адрес `/cgi-bin/hi3510/ptzctrl.cgi`: act=right указывает направление, act=stop указывает остановиться. В ответ камера присылает всего лишь слово Succeed. Всё! Никакого HTML, никакого выдёргивания JS. Просто отправляем такой же запрос где-нибудь в своём коде, а ползунки прикрутить можно какие угодно, совсем не обязательно их выдёргивать. В камерах Axis должно быть что-то очень похожее на это (возможно, вместо скорости координаты, но не суть)

Comment: И, кстати, ползунки Axis по закону вам не принадлежат и вы не имеете права их выдёргивать, интеллектуальная собственность, всё такое

Comment: Большое спасибо @andreymal, Вы очень помогли)